# IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ImportException: 'No module named fcntl' - IronPython C#

Tags: c#, matplotlib

Olá, boa tarde.
Estou fazendo uma chamada a um arquivo .py, que se encontra no escopo do meu diretório da aplicação, e é retornado o seguinte erro:

> IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ImportException: 'No module named matplotlib.pyplot'

Na chamada do botão, estou pedindo para verificar os Paths da versão 3.8 do Python, e ainda sim aparece esta mensagem para mim.

Observe o código abaixo:

```
 //Instanciando o PythonEngine
            var MotorPython = Python.CreateEngine();

            //Definido os paths da IronPython
            var PathsIronPyton = MotorPython.GetSearchPaths();
            PathsIronPyton.Add(@"C:\Python27\Lib");
            PathsIronPyton.Add(@"C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\");
            PathsIronPyton.Add(@"C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib");
            PathsIronPyton.Add(@"C: \Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38 - 32\Lib");
            PathsIronPyton.Add(@"C: \Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38 - 32\Lib\site-packages\");
            PathsIronPyton.Add(@"C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib");
            MotorPython.SetSearchPaths(PathsIronPyton);

            //Lendo o fonte em .py
            var SourceCodePython = MotorPython.CreateScriptSourceFromFile(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "python-statistics", "calc2.py"));

            //Definido o Escopo
            var ScopePython = MotorPython.CreateScope();

            SourceCodePython.Execute(ScopePython);

            var ClasseCalc = ScopePython.GetVariable("calc");

            //Inicializando a classe calc.py
            var InstanciaCalc = MotorPython.Operations.CreateInstance(ClasseCalc);

            InstanciaCalc.grafCasosAtivos(true);
        }
        catch 
        {
            throw;
        }
```

Me apresenta essa mensagem de erro no catch. Alguém já conseguiu solucionar o verificar o motivo dessa mensagem? Observação: Ao rodar no modo Debug, consigo ver que

Comment: Ao rodar no modo debug você consegue ver o que?

Comment: IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ImportException: 'No module named matplotlib.pyplot'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pesquisei e recentemente, descobri que o IronPython, não tem suporte para esta biblioteca. Infelizmente.